# No Access-Control-Allow-Origin header JS Get Request

Tags: javascript, ajax, get, request, header

I Have write a code using JS, to send GET Request to a URL. This error appears in the console when I'am clicking the button to make the GET request: [ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uKOZR.png)

Below you can see the code, I saw some solutions but it didn't work for me. I'am working in a index.html file should I insert something in my code to fix this error?

```js
    function call()
    {
        var url = "http://urlexample";
        
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("GET", url);
        
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
           if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
              console.log(xhr.status);
              console.log(xhr.responseText);
           }};
        
        xhr.send();     
    }
```

```html
<button onclick="call();">Make a request</button>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource—when trying to get data from a REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43871637/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource-whe)

Comment: No I tried something like this but I have the same error.